# Move block in catalog_product_view layout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, catalog, product-view

I'm using **Magento 2.1** and I just wanted to move a block in the product view layout, extending the existing layout.

My theme inherits from blank theme, and I have tried just to copy/paste what is done in **magento-luma** theme, and how it is explained in the official guide

([here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html) and [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange))

So I just created an extending `catalog_product_view.xml` inside

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout
```

with a similar content of what is done in luma-theme, like this

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

but actually, nothing is moving.

I also tried overriding the layout, either the theme layout, as well as the module base layout, as mentioned in the official guide about overriding themes ([here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html)).

Cleared cache several times, regenerated static files, but nothing continues to happen.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

checking for erros in log files, in system.log I found this:

```
    [2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_411c931cf412fc3b1664f9d6f27c7e38e and handles default, catalog_product_view, catalog_product_view_id_1, catalog_product_view_sku_Primo%20prodotto, catalog_product_view_type_virtual: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles 1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.price' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.review', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.price' respectively. [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.price.final' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.sku', but their parents are different: 'product.info.price' and 'product.info.stock.sku' respectively. [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.social' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product.info.extrahint' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'view.addto.wishlist' tries to reorder itself towards 'view.addto.requisition', but their parents are different: 'product.info.addto' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addtocart.paypal', but their parents are different: 'product.info.addtocart' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:48] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4c7dd4384a0ea945ae0d791fa12c5fba3 and handles review_product_listajax: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-08-30 13:21:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4c7dd4384a0ea945ae0d791fa12c5fba3 and handles review_product_listajax: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

but actually, updating the catalog_product_view.xml to this

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
         <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true" />
        </body>
    </page>
```

still does not reflect on the frontend, nor in the log files. It seems simply ignored.

I am in developer mode and disabled all cache files.

**EDIT2:**

comes out that the system.log errors are a not yet corrected Magento bug, and nothing important.

The other try I have done is to modify the catalog_product_view.xml in Magento/luma theme and it behaves exactly as expected.

Tried to extend another layout in my theme and no effect.

In the end I have created other two themes from scratch, one inheriting from blank and the other from luma, and the remove instruction works. But still no luck with move.

Comment: path should be `Magento_Catalog`..  is it typo? Because "C" should be capital

Comment: yes it is a typo. thx I correct.

Comment: Where are you trying to move it? My title is at top anyway. Setting this <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.media"/> moves it to bottom however so this may be worth checking to debug.

Comment: if you compare the position of the main title (<div class="page-title-wrapper product">....</div> ) in blank theme, with its position in luma, you can see that in blank theme it is directly inside the <main id="maincontent">...</main>, whereas in luma, it is moved inside <div class="column main">...</div>, which is inside <main>..</main>. I just want to play around with layouts, I don't have a precise objective to achieve.

Comment: Yeah did you try the bit of code i pasted to see if it moved? I think you will need to change destination to move outside of the block on right however. e.g. <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/> will movwe it outside of that block and to top of page..

Comment: yes i tried it. no luck

Comment: So you have the remove working in your own theme now? What does your move argument look like?

Comment: actually also the move magically works, the one in your example. Probably i was just making some mistake or left cache enabled. Dunno. Magento's magic :) i will accept your answer, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block is currently at the top of product.info.main so may not be moving due to this.

Try below to move to another container:

**e.g**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

Study `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` to see what containers exist and what they contain.

You can then set the destination to the container you wish. To order within the container you can change the `before` or `after` argument to the name of the block you want it to be before or after or `before="-"` for before all or `after="-"` for after all.

See below for a lot more on layouts:

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: thank you for the answer. I already tried different combinations of the move/remove instructions and studied all the sections concerning the layout manipulation. i created my theme and successfully extended the blank one with less and stuff like that. But i do not understand my problems with the layout. Dunno what are they concerned... oh, and i am using magento 2.1.7, not 2.0

Comment: So nothing you change is reflecting on the frontend? Ok i changed the link they should be pretty much the same however

Comment: yes no change on the xml layout is reflecting on the front. i have also tried to use the default.xml as a last chance, but nothing. only changing phtml templates and static styling files. there must be something before that i am missing,but have no clue on what. Ok for the link, it was just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: hmm i'm not sure you seem like your very much on the right lines. I run in developer mode for dev with no cache. Changing the layouts instantly reflect for me in that situation. In production i normally run setup:upgrade compile, deploy  and then that works also.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in var/log?

Comment: Ok, I checked for some errors in log files. I will post an update to the main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64825/discussion-between-sissy-and-harri).